# Текст под градиентом? Как реализовать на CSS

Tags: css3, svg, текст

Подскажите, как (если это возможно) реализовать такой эффект к тексту, как представлен на картинке.
[image: текст картинки с градиентом]
Средствами CSS возможно SVG

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text_shape {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FDBF01 0%, #DC6E00 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.text_effect:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-size: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 14;
}
```

```html
<p class="text_shape text_effect" data-text="Ваш Бонус">Ваш Бонус</p>
```

Я попытался сделать через data-text и :after но пока ничего толкового не вышло. Текста с таким эффектом в задаче много, по этому сохранять его png или BASE64 не вариант

Comment: C помощью text-shadow нельзя?

Comment: [Артур Булшитов  копию сделал на SVG](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/215815509) вот здесь : https://jsfiddle.net/qwr043gp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 82px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-shadow: 
  -0   -4px 2px #E49202,
   0   -4px 2px #E49202,
  -0    4px 2px #E49202,
   0    4px 2px #E49202,
     0    4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px  0   2px #E49202,
   4px  0   2px #E49202,
  -4px  0   2px #E49202,
   4px  0   2px #E49202,
  -1px -4px 2px #E49202,
   1px -4px 2px #E49202,
  -1px  4px 2px #E49202,
   1px  4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px -1px 2px #E49202,
   4px -1px 2px #E49202,
  -4px  1px 2px #E49202,
   4px  1px 2px #E49202,
  -2px -4px 2px #E49202,
   2px -4px 2px #E49202,
  -2px  4px 2px #E49202,
   2px  4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px -2px 2px #E49202,
   4px -2px 2px #E49202,
  -4px  2px 2px #E49202,
   4px  2px 2px #E49202,
  -3px -4px 2px #E49202,
   3px -4px 2px #E49202,
  -3px  4px 2px #E49202,
   3px  4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px -3px 2px #E49202,
   4px -3px 2px #E49202,
  -4px  3px 2px #E49202,
   4px  3px 2px #E49202,
  -4px -4px 2px #E49202,
   4px -4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px  4px 2px #E49202,
   4px  4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px -4px 2px #E49202,
   4px -4px 2px #E49202,
  -4px  4px 2px #E49202,
   4px  4px 2px #E49202,
   0    4px 2px #592910,
   0    4px 2px #592910,
  -4px  0   2px #592910,
   4px  0   2px #592910,
  -4px  0   2px #592910,
   4px  0   2px #592910,
  -1px  10px 2px #592910,
   1px  10px 2px #592910,
  -4px  1px 2px #592910,
   4px  1px 2px #592910,
  -2px  10px 2px #592910,
   2px  10px 2px #592910,
  -4px  10px 2px #592910,
   4px  10px 2px #592910,
  -3px  10px 2px #592910,
   3px  10px 2px #592910,
  -4px  8px 2px #592910,
   4px  8px 2px #592910,
  -4px  10px 2px #592910,
   4px  10px 2px #592910,
  -4px  10px 2px #592910,
   4px  10px 2px #592910;
}
```

```html
<p class='text_effect' data-text="ВАШ БОНУС">Ваш Бонус</p>
```

Может как-нибудь с помощью тени? Хотя на картинке намного красивее)

Comment: весьма недурно, еще немного тени под белым и будет очень похоже